# PyCharm- Creating Output file

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm

has anyone any experience of using PyCharm? I have created a script, which runs and executes as I had hoped. It is to count the number of unique fields and, remove the dupes. I have been able to reconfigure the settings so that the correct py script reads in the correct txt file. What I still need to produce however is the new output file with only unique fields. Also what is concerning is that when it runs, a message appears satying "Too much output to produce". I then get the message Process finished with exit code 0.

Comment: thats from printing to the console window ... not from writing to a file ... this might help http://forum.jetbrains.com/thread/PyCharm-1592

Answer (score 0):

in PyCharm when the output is to large you will get the "Too much output to produce" message.  what you can do is write your output to a text file. view the script below.

```
file = open('outputfile.txt','w')
value = str(field) + '\n'
file.write(value)
file.close()
```

Comment: Thank you Luis and Kevin for your comments. I have now changed the original code i had written and getting some unexpected errors. See below:

Comment: #!usr/bin/python
import sys

#Reading Input file
fh = open(sys.argv[1]).readlines()

#printing no of lines in the input file
print "Total lines in the input file",len(fh)

#temporary dictionary to store the unique records/rows
temp = {}

#counter to count unique items
count = 0

Comment: for i in range(82,9054,1):
 if i not in temp: #if row is not there in dictionary i.e it is unique so store it into a dictionary
  temp[fh[i]] = 1;
  count += 1
 else: #if exact row is there then print duplicate record and dont store that
  print "Duplicate Records",fh[i]
  continue;

#once all the records are read print how many unique records are there
#u can print all unique records by printing temp
print "Unique records",count,len(temp)
fh = open((sys.argv[2]),'w')
fh.write(temp)
fh.close()

Comment: I had to input the code in 2 comments as there was too many characters. Can you see why this is not working?